# word for 'ready in a minute'

Tags: single-word-requests

there is a word for lies like 'ready in a minute' 'I'll be right there''back in a moment' etc.
What is it? Is there a website with definitions for such?

Comment: *Lies* seems rather harsh:are you not interested in the situations where these phrases are in fact true?

Comment: Hmm. I seem to have missed the "Lies" bit.

Comment: Since you call them "lies", I assume you're asking for a word to identify a class of  unrealistically optimistic assurances (where the speaker knows perfectly well his ***hollow promise*** won't in fact be honoured). Are you specifically only interested in optimistic *time* estimates? What about the salesman's *This product will give you years of faithful service*, when he knows it's poor quality and not likely to last more than a few days?

Comment: maybe dissimulation or dissembling ?? sort of

Comment: fixed lies.(expressions)...

Comment: Would appear to be sadly a disappearing user, and we'll never know the answer to the duality F.F. explains - so the question is really unanswerable. Close.

Comment: They can be called [**white lies**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/white+lie) or [**half-truths**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Half-truths) Frankly, I'm amazed no one has suggested any of these. Fumble Fingers suggestion is very good, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word means "taking something to unrealistic extremes"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43632/what-word-means-taking-something-to-unrealistic-extremes)

Answer (score 1):

Although not specific to the statements you mention, they are a kind of ***hyperbole***.

> 1. obvious and intentional exaggeration.
> 2. an extravagant statement or figure of speech not intended to be taken literally, as “to wait an eternity.”.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Dictionay.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hyperbole)</sub>

Comment: 'We waited an eternity' is more extravagant than 'Back in a moment'.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for another word for such “lies,” regardless of context, I’d call them either “[exaggerations](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyperbole)” or “[hyperboles](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyperbole).”

If you’re after a word that covers only such “lies” when they relate to underestimating time, as in your examples, I’d call them “[stalls](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stall).”

> stall: 2  (stôl) n. A ruse or tactic used to mislead or delay.

Answer (score 0):

> Temporize

is one of my favorite words, it's possibly part of what you mean here?

(It just means dilly-dally, put-off ... avoid making a decision, hang about instead of being decisive.)